# Confused About Angular 15 material upgrade? Should my tags all reflect mat-mdc-.....?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, angular-material-15

We have recently upgraded to 15. Everything is running stable, obviously we found a few places where material changes changed how our applications appear to end users.

However, I am confused, after running the migration script, while our browser console now displays "mat-mdc-...." tags, none of our actual html has been converted. Is this case correct? Should all of our html tags reflect  etc?

Thank you for your time, I have been going through other stack answers and they are leaving me very confused.

None of our modules are incorporating any of the Legacy modules or components as far as I am able to tell.

```
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        aria-label="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        formControlName="email"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Adam Raetz, how did you fix this mdc issues ? I too have exactly same confusion.
Also, how did you fix the unit tests filing after MDC migration and how did you modify css selectors in the SCSS files where MDC has left TODO comments?